# How to get Java 8 hour as parameter?

Tags: java-8, java-time

I want to create a method that gets 24 hour format parameter for the user.

Something like: `set24HourTime(LocalDateTime hourTIme)`.

I know I can do it simple by defining an int as a parameter, but I wondered if it can be done with java build in API?

Comment: You can use java.time.LocalTime

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to take an integer as argument, but make sure it's between 0 and 23 included? You can always create your own Hour class wrapping an int and checking the bounds.

Comment: Well, integer is the simplest solution, but it there any why getting the time with java.time.LocalTime  as a parameter?

Comment: The comment of JB_Nizet is right but honestly: Why do you look for a special API to avoid an int parameter and a simple check if this parameter is within range 0-23? An extra class seems to be overkill. The task is way too simple to justifiy a new class. About your original question: No, such an API does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a LocalDateTime param, then the value is already in 24 hour format.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getHour--

just return hourTIme.getHour()